# sp2013: Where can I find info about display templates and javascript/jquery to generate fancy search result webparts?

Tags: display-template

I am using SP2013. I have a list with items. These items I am showing in a search content webpart. Now I like to do fancy things in javascript and jquery. Where can I find more info about these? Tutorials or youtube movies are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can find thousand of refer out side there :)

I can suggest to you to start from the MSDN ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945138.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/05/28/stage-11-upload-and-apply-display-templates-to-the-content-search-web-part.aspx)
In this blog post we'll learn:

1. About display templates
2. How to upload display templates
3. How to apply display templates to a Content Search Web Part

In SharePoint, go to Site settings --> Master pages and page layouts --> Display Templates --> Content Web Parts, and check that the four files have been added. Also notice that an associated .js (JavaScript) file has automatically been created for each display template.

[image]

Comment: This part is the easiest one. I know this already. Ofcorse many thanks. But I would like to know how to play with layout of the control template and item template with jquery.